# CSS menu and html problem

Tags: html, css

I'm having troubles with CSS Menu. I'm developing site on Joomla.
I'll post here CSS and HTML code, so you can copy it into a file.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
</body>
<div class="left-menu">
    <ul class="menu-winery">
        <li class="parent active item5">
            <a href=""><span>ღვინო</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li class="parent active item6">
                    <a href=""><span>TELIANI VALLEY</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="item7">
                            <a href=""><span>ლეგენდა</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="current" class="parent active item8">
                            <a href=""><span>ღვინოები</span></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="active item10">
                                    <a href=""><span>ქვევრის</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item51">
                                    <a href=""><span>დაძველებული</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item52">
                                    <a href=""><span>სამშვენისი</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item53">
                                    <a href=""><span>ადგილწარმოშობის</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item54">
                                    <a href=""><span>ჯიშური</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="item55">
                                    <a><span>სადესერტო</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="item9">
                            <a href="javascript:;"><span>ჯილდოები</span></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="item57">
                    <a><span>MOSSANO DEPUIS 1893</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item58">
                    <a><span>TELURI</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item59">
                    <a><span>OLD GRUZIA</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item60">
                    <a><span>GRUZIA</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item61">
                    <a><span>KVARELI</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="item62">
                    <a><span>LAZURI</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item63">
            <a><span>ცქრიალა ღვინო</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="item64">
            <a><span>ჭაჭა</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="item65">
            <a><span>ქართული ბრენდი</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</head>
```

And here's CSS Code:

```
.menu-winery { margin:0; padding:0; width:145px; list-style:none; }
.menu-winery li a { font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#7b212b; display:block;
     text-decoration:none; text-indent: 10px; margin-bottom: 1px; }
.menu-winery li a:hover { background-color: #7b212b; color:#fff; }   
.menu-winery li.active a { background-color: #7b212b; color:#fff; }  

.menu-winery li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }
.menu-winery li ul  li {  text-indent: 20px; }
.menu-winery li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#808285; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; margin-bottom: 1px; }
.menu-winery li ul li a:hover { background-color: #887b32; color:#fff; }        
.menu-winery li ul li.active a { background-color: #887b32; color:#fff; width:200px; height:20px; }     

.menu-winery li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;  }
.menu-winery li ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#cbbc9a; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; text-indent: 28px; margin-bottom: 1px; }  
.menu-winery li ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #cbbc9a; color:#fff; }      
.menu-winery li ul li ul li.active a { background-color: #cbbc9a; color:#fff; }     

.menu-winery li ul li ul li ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;  }   
.menu-winery li ul li ul li ul li a { background-color: #fff; font: normal 12px/20px sylfaen, calibri, Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    color:#887b32; display:block; text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; text-indent: 33px; margin-bottom: 1px; }  
.menu-winery li ul li ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: #e2dec9; color:#fff; list-style:none; }
.menu-winery li ul li ul li ul li.active a { background-color: #e2dec9; color:#fff; list-style:none; }
```

so here, I have a problem with ACTIVE state of LI's. If I put active class to A tag, everything works fine. But in joomla I'll have to make an overide of main menu module (and I have to idea what to change there...)

Maybe anyone knows how to fix this problem. When Active Li is set, all sub ul-s that are inside of it get parents color.

Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: can you add link of your joomla? Probably it's a specificity problem.

Comment: http://telianivalley.com/new/index.php?option=com_telianiwines&view=winelegendlist&catid=1&Itemid=7   <--- this is the link... in this version I removed CSS with active. Didn't want to make it look ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla uses the id #current for active menu items, so try

```
.menu-winery li#current a { background-color: #7b212b; color:#fff; }
```

Comment: I think that this would have the same effect, but it's worth trying. But in this project's case Joomla doesn't display ID Current, and that's an interesting fact too, why it doesn't display ID="Current".. maybe you know...